# Drupal custom form twice on same page, i need the errors displayed in the one submitted and not on both

Tags: drupal

I've a custom module that builds a form with a couple of fields, so far so good.
In one of my pages, i print this form twice (different blocks), the form gets the same "form_id", so when i submit one of them and get an error, both of them get the error highlighted, and the fields populated.
I want that only the form i submit gets the errors, is there a way to do this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, to do this you need to use the hook_forms.
This hook only gets called when the form_id passed to a drupal_get_form doesn't exist, this is important, if you want to use this, make sure your calls use a non existing form_id, for example:

```
//Defining the form:
function mx_wtransnet_form_contacto($form, &$form_state, $block = null, $formType = null) {  
}
```

I want to use this form multiple times and get different error handlers, instead of loading my form (mx_transnet_form_contacto), i'll call a non existing one:

```
$form = drupal_get_form("mx_wtransnet_form_contacto_invalid", "contacto-mini");
```

Then i create my hook:

```
function mx_wtransnet_forms($form_id, $args) {
        $forms = array();
        if (strpos($form_id, '_contacto_') !==false) {
                $forms[$form_id] = array(
                'callback' => 'mx_wtransnet_form_contacto',
                 );
        }
return $forms;
}
```

This function will catch all my druapl_get_form calls that don't exist, so i can process/direct them, in my example, what i do is simply check that the form_id contains *contacto* and then set the callback for this form to the original function.

Answer (score 0):

In this case better to create another form with different "form_id" but with the same submit handler.

Another case: when you output same form twice on the page it also may get JS errors because ID of form elements are the same.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't repeat the form code and its submit handler(DRY principle), I would recommend create a custom function that has the form array

```
function form_my_custom($form_id){
 $form['my_first_field'] = array(); 
 $form['my_second_field'] = array();
 $form['#attributes']['id'] = $form_id; 
 $form['my_submit_button'] = array(
   '#submit' => array('my_custom_form_submit')
 ); 
 return $form;  

}

function my_block1_form(){ 
  return my_custom_form('my_form_id_1'); 
}

function my_block2_form(){ 
  return my_custom_form('my_form_id_2'); 
} 

function my_custom_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state){ 
  // your submit handler. 
}
```